# Dynamically Inject script to HTML from controller in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm a newbee to Angular and frontend; sorry if my question is simple:

I have the following code in my controller where I'm populating `$window.user` data which is used in the script [2] which I added in my HTML file

```
$scope.currentUser.$promise.then(function (data) {
    $window.user = {};
    $window.user.firstName= data.firstName
}
```

And here is the script which I added in HTML
[2]

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://test.com/embed.js" async></script>
```

However my data (`$window.user.firstName`) gets passed too late after loading the script; I think I have two options:

1) dynamically inject/load my script to my HTML from my controller after getting `$window.user.firstName`. If that's the right way, how would you do that?

2)read `$window.user.firstName` on `$window.onload`?

Added: It is worth mentioning if I do not populate $windows.user.firstname by promise and use some dummy data outside of that data gets used by script and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
$('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://myscript/embed.js" async></script>').appendTo('body');
```

^ It works fine. However if you see any problem with this solution please write here. Thanks!

Comment: Your controller is not meant to interact directly with dom, like, <body>.